# spring boot read properties file from different maven module

Tags: java, spring-mvc, properties, spring-boot

My maven project have three modules, `web`, `service`, `common`

Some parts of my project like this:

```
demo-parent:
  --web
    --src
      --main
        --java
          --Application.java
        --resources
          --application.properties
          --application-mysql.properties
   --service
   --common
     --src
       --main
         --java
           --ErrorCode.java
         --resources
           --application-errors.properties
```

In web moudle `Application.java`, I want to read contents from `common` moudle `application-errors.properties`.

Here is my `ErrorCode.java` in `common`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:application-errors.properties")
public class ErrorCode {
    private int code;
    private String message;

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Because I want to use this `application-errors.properties` from `web` module, So in `web` moudle, in `Application.java`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("application-mysql.properties"),
    @PropertySource("application-errors.properties")
})
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ErrorCode.class})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        application.run(args);
    }
}
```

Now, I add `EnableConfigurationProperties` to `Application.java` which contains `main` method, and I can get key and value from `application-errors.properties` file, my question is :

If I want to invoke appliction-errors.propertie in **other module** like service, and service **do not have a main method**, what should I do ?

We can read properties file by using java `Properties` class, but I want to use **spring way**.

Anything advice is welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't that be @PropertySource("classpath:application-mysql.properties") and @PropertySource("classpath:application-errors.properties") in your web module?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of accessing application-error.properties, you can auto wire `ErrorCode` class in your services in other modules (assuming the ErrorCode is present on the build classpath of those services).

First define your error message configuration component.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:application-error.properties")
public class ErrorCode {

    private int code;
    private String message;

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

Auto wire the configuration component in service

```
@Component
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private ErrorCode errorCode;


    public void accessErrorCode() {
        System.out.println(errorCode.getCode()); //Print code property
        System.out.println(errorCode.getMessage()); //print message property
    }

}
```

Enabling auto configuration in spring application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).web(false).application();
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = application.run(args);
        Service s = context.getBean(Service.class);
        s.accessErrorCode();
    }
}
```

As per the Javadocs of `EnableConfigurationProperties`,

> {@link ConfigurationProperties} beans can be registered in the standard way (for
>    * example using {@link Bean @Bean} methods) or, for convenience, can be specified
>    * directly on this annotation.

Thus, all beans defined with annotation `ConfigurationProperties` are detected under application context and can be auto-wired in other services.